# Fix broken <a> decoration with multiple spans

Tags: css, anchor, underline

So, i have

```
<a href="#">R<span class="superscript">5</span></a>
```

and the underline for my anchor is broken (meaning the underline for the R is at the baseline, and the underline for the 5 is in the middle of the R -- because the 5 is small), which i don't want. How do i get the anchor underline to be one unbroken line under both the R and the 5 (at the baseline)?

thanks.

Comment: What does your CSS look like for that part?

Comment: This is only half a question since you're making us guess how you're actually applying the style.

Comment: Is the underline under R5 or just 5?

Comment: The underline is under both the R and the 5, however the line is broken. It is at the baseline under the R, and at the center of the font height (x-height) under the 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it would work or whether there are nicer solutions, but you can remove the underline and add a `bottom-border` to the `a` element.

Comment: that seems to work, altho i'll have to play tricks with the visited color of the bottom-border -- good enough, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You should be using the `<sup>` tag. This works fine for me:

```
<a href="#">R<sup>5</sup></a>
```

with

```
a { text-decoration: underline; }
```

I don't know how you're implementing superscript but I will mention a common reason people why people don't. They think it's deprecated like `<b>` (it isn't) or that it isn't semantic (it is).

Comment: ah, didn't know about <sup> actually :*)

i was using
.superscript {
 font-size:xx-small; 
 vertical-align:top;
}

Answer (score 0):

It would help actually knowing what css is applied to both of those, but you can play around with the `line-height` property and explicitly define a consistent `vertical-align` value for both of those, if not you could try a `bottom-border` instead of `text-decoration:underline`.

```
a span.superscript { vertical-align:baseline; line-height:1; }
```

Edit: I'm not experiencing it @ http://jsbin.com/orudi

```
  <a href="#">R<sup>5</sup></a>

  <style>
      body { width:5em; margin:0 auto; font-size:100%; padding:5em 0 0; background:#000; }
      a { text-decoration:underline; color:#fff; font-size:5em; }
      a sup { vertical-align:top; font-size:xx-small; font-size:.5em; }
  </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

> ah, didn't know about `<sup>` actually :*) i was using `.superscript { font-size:xx-small; vertical-align:top; }`

If you wanted to use [CSS for the superscript](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp), you would need this:

```
.superscript {vertical-align:super;}
```

But, as pointed out by [cletus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586742/fix-broken-a-decoration-with-multiple-spans/1586757#1586757), just go with the semantically correct and still in fashion use of the `<sup>` tag.

Comment: interesting -- actually vertical-align:super; and <sup> push the letter above the line height which isn't as purdy as vertical-align:top... but i'm splitting hairs, obviously. thanks all.

Comment: superscript is supposed to push it above the line-height/baseline. What you wanted was something like having the text be half the size, but using the same baseline.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this CSS I found, it prevents subscript and superscript from breaking your line-heights. It works for me.

```
sup, sub { vertical-align: baseline; position: relative; top: -0.4em; font-size: 0.75em; font-weight: normal; }
sub { top: 0.4em; }
```

Try the following chemical formulas:

```
MgNaA<sub>l5(</sub>Si<sub>4</sub>O<sub>10</sub>)<sub>3</sub>(OH)<sub>6</sub>
```

or

```
Radioactive Phosphorus-32 is <sup>32</sup>PO<sub>4</sub><sup>3-</sup>
```